# Partial derivatives proof excercise

Tags: calculus, derivatives

I need some help in the proof of the next excercise: 
Proof that $\frac{\partial f}{\partial x} = \frac{\partial f}{\partial y}$ in every point of an open set D if and only if there is $g$ derivable such that $f(x,y) = g(x+y)$ $\forall (x,y) \in D$. 
Please I'm super lost and I don't know which way to go so I can solve it :(

Comment: Is this question correct? Consider $e^{x+y}$. It satisfies the right hand side but not the left.

Comment: @BenjaminWang Check again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**HINT**: If $\nabla f$ is a scalar multiple of $(1,1)$ at each points, then the level curves of $f$ are everywhere orthogonal to $(1,1)$, which means they must be lines $x+y=c$. (I'm assuming that $\nabla f \ne 0$ at each point.)